# Test whether an element exist using Protractor for Angular when the element is created after an http call completes

Tags: angular, protractor

My protractor test doesn't wait for the http call to complete and does not find the element and will fail the test. How do I make the protractor test wait for my http call to complete before looking for the element?

template:

```
<div *ngIf="done" class="myelement">myelement</div>
```

javascript:

```
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(()=> {
        this.done = true;
    })
```

protractor:

```
expect(element(by.className('myelement')).isPresent()).eventually.to.be.true;
```

I get the error "expected false to be true".

If I remove `*ngIf="done"` then my test will pass, so the http call is definitely the issue

Answer (score 0):

Protractor not supply api to wait http call complete, only can wait some element from page.

In you case, you need to wait the element itself by `browser.wait(condition, timeout)`

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser

.wait(EC.presenceOf(by.css('div.myelement')), 15*1000)

.catch(function(err) {
   // if not find the element after 15 seconds (15 * 1000)
   // it will throw timeoutexception, means the element not present
   // so we need to catch and handle it.

   // if not throw timeoutexception, means the element present
   // no need to give one more code line to check `isPresent() === true`
   expect(false).to.be.true;
});
```